# Mysql illegal mix of collations when all collations already standardized

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a strange mysql error: when trying to insert a row into a table that includes the Look Of Disapproval - ಠ_ಠ - I get the following error:

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation = 'select...

Sure enough, some of the tables in my database were set to the `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. I changed all of the tables to `utf8_general_ci`, but the error persists.

What am I missing?

Comment: Collation can also be set at the individual column level. Did you check that?

Comment: Arrgh, I didn't know that. That's exactly what it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collation can also be set at the individual column level.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collations.html
And: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Made it community wiki, so you can accept it without me getting @Dan's rep.

Comment: To see which collation you're using: SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN tablename;
To change it: ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(255)       CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;